# Выбор порядка M для Б-дерева

Tags: c, алгоритм

Есть задание, в котором необходимо реализовать базу данных с использованием деревьев. Было выбрано B-tree. В целом, алгоритм понятен. Только каким образом происходит выбор порядка этого дерева? На чем должен быть основан этот выбор.

Спасибо!

Comment: На компромиссах между количеством и скоростью обмена с диском и размером  используемой памяти. imho на практике нужно измерять и пробовать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно говорят о том, чтоб в памяти узел занимал ровно одну страницу, обычно 4096 байт. Ну и на диске тоже чтобы чтений было поменьше - одним махом считывать блок в память.

По крайней мере в паре книг по Oracle и БД давался именно такой подход.

Comment: Когда-то раньше обмен с диском всегда проходил на уровне целого числа последовательных секторов, умещающихся на одну дорожку, а своппинг на уровне страниц. Сейчас (с появлением большого внутреннего кэша у дисков) первое стало не актуальным, как собственно и второе (но уже по причине, что когда в системе начинается своппинг мы (привыкшие к хорошему) считаем это неприемлемой деградацией)